# Simple HTML5 keyboard navigation for elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, keyboard-events, arrow-functions

I'm trying to implement some keyboard navigation (arrows **left**, **right** & **enter/space** to select) into my website. I'm guessing some `jQuery` will be required for this! Here's an idea of what I'm looking for (see first image). I want to be able to use images where the 'sections' are and have the current selection highlighted.

[image]

Is there a simple way of doing this?

Furthermore, if there is a simple way of doing this, how would I expand it to the following:

[image]

jQuery is not my area at all. I've looked everywhere online and I'm finding it extremely hard to find a simple way of implementing keyboard controls into my website. Any links or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

you can do it, just add the code that you want to the following

```
  $(document).keydown(function(e) {
      switch(e.which) {
          case 37: // left
              moveInSectorToLeft();
          break;

         case 38: // up
             nothing(); //Dont know if you want to use it
         break;

         case 39: // right
             moveInSectorToRight();
         break;

         case 40: // down
             selectCurrentSection();
         break;

         default: return; 
     }
     e.preventDefault(); 
  });
```

you can check an example in this fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/ew8Lnt83/

Comment: Wow, thanks for the quick response. I checked out the jsfiddle, but I can't work out how to impliment it.. Hate to ask you to spell it out for me. Is there a way you could give a made example?

Comment: you cant make the fiddle work? (just press the keys left, right or down), or you dont understand how to use the code that i gave you to your propouse?, if thats the case i would gladly help you, chat?

Comment: @Kaiido yes, i removed it in the fiddle, i keep it in the answer because from what i understand, he wanted it to do nothing, but maybe i was wrong :P, sry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: @Shocklo thanks, but no need to mention me, didn't help at all for the answer, just for the formatting :-)

Comment: @Kaiido How do I make the highlighted areas clickable?? I want to be able to use 'enter' key to open url.

Comment: The keyCode for `Return` key is `13` so just add a `case 13: doSomethingWithReturnKey()` in the switch statement

Answer (score 3):

You can use the **keydown** event from jQuery, I wrote a simple fiddle to help you understand how to implement it, I hope it helps:

```
$(function(){
    height = $('#myTable tr').length+1;    
    width = $('#myTable td').length;
    $.each($('#myTable td'), function(key, value){
        $(this).attr('id', key);
    });
});
$(document).keydown(function(e)
{    
   switch(e.which) {        
        case 37: // left
           move(1);
        break;
        case 38: // up
            move(2);
        break;
        case 39: // right
           move(3);
        break;          
        case 40: // down
           move(4);
        break;          
        default: return; // exit this handler for other keys
    }
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent the default action (scroll / move caret)
}); 
function move(direction){
    var cur_id = parseInt($('.selected').attr('id'));
    switch(direction){
        case 1://left
           selectTd(cur_id-1);
            break;
        case 2://up
            selectTd(cur_id-height);
            break;
        case 3://right
            selectTd(cur_id+1);
            break;
        case 4://down
             selectTd(cur_id+height);
            break;

    }

}
function selectTd(id){
    if(id > (width-1) || id < 0) return alert("Out of bounds");
   $('.selected').removeClass('selected');  
   $('#'+id).addClass('selected');     
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/z6gea722/

Comment: That did the trick! Thanks so much guys, I just needed that little bit more of an explanation. Problem solved! :D I'll work on the second part myself and try and post the results here in the next day or two.

Comment: Nice complete answer :P

Comment: If anyone can elaborate to provide code for the second section I would be eternally grateful and build many churches in your honour.

Answer (score 2):

You can check a more robust way of keyboard navigation handling with https://github.com/amanboss9/naviboard library. As `tab` key helps you to navigate through a pattern and lose focus once you are done with the page navigation.`shift`+`tab` helps in reverse navigation but still you have no control over the navigation according to the element overlaying on the screen.

- Include naviBoard library. https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/naviboard@4.1.0/dist/naviboard.min.js
- Use `class` navigable on the desired items.
- Initialize the `naviBoard.setNavigation(parentID)` method with parentID as the id of the parent element of all navigable elements.

You can go through the demo of this by below jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/amanboss9/unf94tjo/3/embedded/result/